# When registering with Google for C2DM notifications can you get an answer even if the servers side is not setup?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I've been trying to implement the C2DMReceiver to receive push notification. I have downloaded and used the Chrome To Phone code and looked at code of some different applications using this service. I have signed my application up at Google and received an e-mail that my application has been accepted. Now I've tried (too many times ;-)  ) just to register and receive some kind of answer, but nothing happens in the C2DMReceiver. It doesn't seem to get called if the service is even running (should I check that somewhere??). I haven't put up a server side application yet because I first just wanted to be able to register before trying to send messages. Now my question is: Should I be receiving anything from the registration request if I don't have a server side application yet? Could this be the problem or am I really doing something wrong in my Android application???

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the answer: Yes, it is possible.

After redoing a lot of what I had done before I found what I was doing wrong, and found the answer: Yes, you can register and receive your registration without implementing the server side application.